# GitLab Markdown Labels

Tags: gitlab, markdown

I'm playing around with Markdown and have a question about it:

I want to work with labels. For example:

[image: Example]

In the third column there are two labels. I would like to use these, depending on the priority. If the task is Low, then the High label must be removed. I am only missing the small x to remove the label.

[image: remove label]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I think this is not relative to git, but to github, gitlab or other git

Comment: [tag:git] itself does not interact with markdown in any way that's relevant to this question. This is one of these cases where [tag:github]/[tag:gitlab] or whatever else you use to host/render those sites becomes relevant. Actually re-reading the question, it has become increasingly unclear what exactly you're editing and what you're asking about. It's certainly not just git and markdown, neither of which provide a "small x to remove the label".

Comment: Sorry, you are right, it is GitLab.

Comment: The primary question is why the labels in the sidebar have an x to remove but the labels in the Iussue description do not. I can add the labels with ~label

Comment: "What am i doing wrong?"—not showing the Markdown source in your question, for one thing :-). But I suspect this isn't supported. Without seeing the source I'm only guessing, but I suspect you're doing something like `~High ~Low` in your Markdown. That explicitly adds each label to the table, which is very different from saying "all labels attached to this issue". If there were something like `~(All)` that expanded to all labels, yeah, this might make sense.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for your answer. You are right, I work with `~High / ~Low` in Markdown. _"That explicitly adds each label to the table, which is very different from saying "all labels attached to this issue". If there were something like ~(All) that expanded to all labels, yeah, this might make sense."_ Ok, that makes sense of course.